# Condition on $n$ for no sequence to exist

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

I've an integer $n\geq3$. What's the minimum possible value of $n$ so that no sequence $a_0,a_1,...,a_{n-1}$ exists where for all i:-

1. $1\leq a_i\leq10^9$ and all $a_i$s are distinct
2. gcd$(a_i,a_{(i+1)mod\ n})>1$
3. gcd$(a_i,a_{(i+1)mod\ n},a_{(i+2)mod\ n})=1$.

What I thought was that all I've to do is to find prime numbers, until $p_i*p_{i+1}>10^9$. Then, I can assign these consecutive products to my $a_i$s, that is, $a_i=p_i*p_{i+1}$ for $0\leq i\leq n-2$ and $a_{n-1}=p_{n-1}*p_0$ ($p_0=2$). However, I'm not getting the correct answer using this. Can someone please tell me what did I miss in these? Thanks:)

Comment: Hi & welcome to MSE. One thing I want to make sure is I believe you intend your condition #$2$ to be for all $i$, not just for some $i$, is that correct?

Comment: Yes, point 1,2 and 3 all for all i

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For instance, you could, after your cycle, write $p_2p_4$ then $p_4p_6$ then $p_6p_2$. There was a similar question asked yesterday (link : [Sequence of N numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3064225/sequence-of-n-numbers/3064239#3064239) ) for which my answer proves that for no sequence to exist, $n$ must be greater than $p(p-1)/2$, where $p$ is odd and there are at least $p$ prime numbers lower than $10^{4.5}$. (Meaning we have very crudely $n \geq 720,000$).

Edit: it turns out we can take $p=3401$, leading to $n \geq 5,781,700$.

Then again, this bound is not, and by far, the best one: I still could add $2*65537$ somewhere, for instance.

Comment: Where exactly should I put $p_2p_4$ and all those, because the condition 2 and 3 might be a problem if I'm not wrong

Comment: No it won’t be a problem, I think.

Comment: Ok, I'll check that out. Thanks a lot

Comment: I got it. Thanks